# How to do a vlookup for each result found by regexreplace?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet cell A1 with markdown like this:

```
Param  | Value                | Units
   --- |     ---              | ---
**K1** |    [PS1\Geral_K1]    |ºC
**K2** |    [PS1\Geral_K2]    |ºC
**K3** |    [PS1\Geral_K3]    |ºC
```

All if this is on the same cell, A1.
PS1\Geral_K? is a param to be fetched from another sheet.
So I need to extract the string inside [] and make a `vlookup` to get the valor for this param.

I already have this code to check I get the result for each group found.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\[([^]]+)\]","$1")
```

Now I want to use "$1" to `vlookup` in another table for each of the following

```
PS1\Geral_K1
PS1\Geral_K2
PS1\Geral_K3
```

how can I do it ???

This is the result I want to have in B1

```
Param  |     Value | Units
---    |    ---    | ---
**K1** |    100    |ºC
**K2** |    20     |ºC
**K3** |    30     |ºC
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DfuhSTUg9yYfUwQ4iMi7myxmUsQyiNMqenp4u2C1ZVE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

paste in **D2** and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 QUERY(QUERY({Campos!A:A, Campos!B:B&"♣"&Campos!D:D&"♠"}, 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A2&"'"), , 999^99),
 " ", CHAR(10)), "♣", " "), "♠", " °C")))
```

[image: 0]